# Find specific string from response in php

Tags: php

I am getting following response

```
{"success":true,"error":false,"code":"SJKUT3GR"}
```

I just want to print **SJKUT3GR** from above.

anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) perhaps? Have you tried it?

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = json_decode($response);
echo $data->code;
```

Comment: `"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved."`

Comment: @Lix Don't tell me, tell the OP, or vote to close.

Comment: Already done both. I just don't feel the need to encourage people to ask these types of questions by providing "copy paste-able" answers.

Comment: I'm usually a stickler as well. But sometimes the answer is just so simple that it's easier to just give it than frustrate the poster.